# How to fix "X must have 2 or fewer dimensions" error in pyplot from matplotlib using the .boxplot function?

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I want to create one figure with 2 boxplots using pyplot from matplotlib in python.

I am working with the iris dataset which provides petal length for 150 flowers from three types: Setosa, Versicolor, Virginica.
I want to create one boxplot for the petal length of Setosa and one boxplot for 
the petal length of Versicolor, all on the same figure.

I based my code on this tutorial: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pyplots/boxplot_demo_pyplot.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pyplots-boxplot-demo-pyplot-py

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# From the iris dataset I create a dataframe which contains only the features 
# of the flowers (sepal length, sepal width, petal length, petal width and the 
# flower type. 

data = load_iris()
X= data["data"]
y = data ["target"]
iris=pd.DataFrame(X)
iris["target"]=y
iris.columns=data['feature_names']+["target"]
iris["target"]=iris["target"].apply(lambda x:'Setosa' if x == 0 else 'Versicolor' if x == 1 else 'Virginica')

# I create my sub-dataframes which each contain the petal length of one type of flower 
ar1 = np.array(iris.loc[lambda iris: iris["target"] == "Setosa", ["petal width (cm)"]])
ar2 = np.array(iris.loc[lambda iris: iris["target"] == "Versicolor", ["petal width (cm)"]])

# This works: 
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.boxplot(ar1)
plt.show()

# But this doesn't work:
data1 = [ar1, ar2] 
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.boxplot(data1)
plt.show()
```

I expect a figure with 2 boxplots. Instead I get the error: "ValueError: X must have 2 or fewer dimensions". However ar1 and ar2 have 2 dimensions exactly like shown in the matplotlib exemple mentioned above.

Thank you very much for your help,

Comment: What's the shape of `arr1` and `arr2` (i.e. what does `print(arr1.shape)` give)?

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that

```
ar1 = np.array(iris.loc[lambda iris: iris["target"] == "Setosa", ["petal width (cm)"]])
```

creates a 2D array of shape `(50,1)`. So what you can do is flatten the array first,

```
data1 = [ar1.flatten(), ar2.flatten()] 
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.boxplot(data1)
```